# ajax call web service: return undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a jquery ajax call asp.net web service but it is not working. I got an error:

**isValid is underfined.**

I set a breakpoint and found that the code never reaches web service.
Jquery:

```
<script src="../jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function ValidateUserName() {
        var isValid;
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "UserNameWebService.asmx/ValidateUserName",
            data: "{'strUsername': '" + $("#<%=TextUserName.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                isValid = data;
            }
        });
         return isValid;
        } 
</script>
```

web service code:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class UserNameWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public bool ValidateUserName(string strUsername)
    {
        \\ then return something by logic
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used Firebug or something similar to watch the request/response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `isValid` before your Ajax is complete.
The best thing to do is write a function which is called on the completion of your Ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "UserNameWebService.asmx/ValidateUserName",
        data: "{'strUsername': '" + $("#<%=TextUserName.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            RenderResult(data);
        }
    });
```

Then deal with the returned data here.

```
function RenderResult(data){
    // handle the returned result here
    var isValid = data;
}
```

Comment: Well I wouldn't do this because you are not going to be returning anything from this. You want to update your UI/Result within this function.

Comment: can we handle the return in your code like this? function RenderResult(data){ if (data.value ==false) return false;else return true;}

Comment: You will not be returning anything. Update your UI from this function. So what ever you are doing with the result of `ValidateUserName` do here. e.g. function RenderResult(data){ if ( data == true ){ alert("Username is not valid"); } };

Comment: But I do want to return something. My original question is to validate a textbox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252864/validateusername-is-undefined/10255251#10255251

Comment: This is not how Ajax works. You need to wait for the result from the Ajax call. By this time, your call to the function `ValidateUserName` has already exited, so you need to deal with the result from within the `success` method of the Ajax call.